# Match Uppercase and Spaces

Tags: regex, r

Match "SCOPE OF AUDIT", but not "Scope of Audit".

I know that I can match a single word that is capitalized, like "RECOMMENDATION":

```
grepl("^[[:upper:]]+$", "RECOMMENDATION")
```

But how do I match something with a space in it, like "SCOPE OF AUDIT"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be a little more specific. You don't want to match any string that has a lower letter? So, just try `!grepl("[a-z]",x)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
 grepl("^[[:upper:] ]+$", x)
 #[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

[`regex101`](https://www.regex101.com/r/mH2eR4/1)

#### data

```
 x <- c("SCOPE OF AUDIT", "Scope of Audit", "SCOPE Of AUDit")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grepl("^(\\s*[[:upper:]]+\\s*)*$",c("SCOPE OF AUDIT", "Scope of Audit"))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

One difference in matching "behavior" between akrun's and my answer is that using akrun's regex will match a string of white spaces while with mine, there would need to be at least 1 upper case character *plus* any number of white spaces (or none).

```
grepl("^[[:upper:] ]+$", " ")            # answer by akrun
#[1] TRUE
grepl("^(\\s*[[:upper:]]+\\s*)*$", " ")  # my answer
#[1] FALSE
```

It's not very clear from the question what behavior the OP would expect in case of a white-space-only string, but based on his own regex attempt (`"^[[:upper:]]+$"`) I *assume* they want to match at least 1 upper case character, otherwise they wouldn't have chosen `+`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
^[\\p{Lu}\\s]+$
```

Here. `\\p{Lu}` matches uppercase letters (Unicode) and `\\s` matches spaces.

An example:

```
grepl("^[\\p{Lu}\\s]+$",c("SCOPE OF AUDIT", "Scope of Audit"), perl = TRUE)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

The regex `\\p{Lu}` allows you to match special uppercase letters too, e.g., `"À"`.

Comment: Thanks for showing this. (+1).  Do you know how the `\\p{Lt}` works?.  I tried `grepl('\\p{Lt}', c('SCOPE', 'Scope', 'scope'), perl=TRUE)`.  It gives all `FALSE`

Comment: @akrun You can find all characters that are matched by `\\p{Lt}` [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lt/list.htm).